# How to trigger a task after build

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I have the following code:

```
import org.openapitools.generator.gradle.plugin.tasks.GenerateTask

plugins {
    id 'org.openapi.generator' version '5.3.1'
}

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceSets {
    main {
        java.srcDirs += "${buildDir}/api/src/main/java/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'javax.validation:validation-api'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations'
    implementation "io.swagger:swagger-annotations"
}

task generateJavaApi(type: GenerateTask) {
    generatorName = "spring"
    inputSpec = "$buildDir/resources/main/static/api.yaml"
    outputDir = "$buildDir/api"
    apiPackage = "org.myApi.api"
    modelPackage = "org.myApi.model"
    configOptions = [
            interfaceOnly  : "true",
            openApiNullable: "false"
    ]
}

configure(generateJavaApi) {
    group = 'openapi tools'
    description = 'Generate Java API'
}

generateJavaApi.dependsOn(build)
```

If I write `build.doLast(generateJavaApi)`, IntelliJ tells me the following: **No candidates found for method call build.dolast.**

Why is that and how would you trigger generateJavaApi after build?

(so that running `gradle build` would automatically also trigger the generation of the java api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is this:

```
build.configure { finalizedBy generateJavaApi }
```